# Can you call forms with a POST from a frame

Tags: asp-classic, frameset

I have a classic ASP system that utilizes Frames today but I need to lock down the system for CSS and CSRF.  I am newer to this language but have been serching for days and can't find the answer.

I would like to change the calls to the forms from Gets to Post.
Do I need to re-write the aplication to all another Form level in between to accomplish this?  Here is the Frame

```
<FRAMESET  COLS="46%,*">
    <FRAME NAME="M_LFrame" SRC="M_LFrm.asp" MARGINWIDTH="5" MARGINHEIGHT="5" SCROLLING="auto" FRAMEBORDER="no">
    <FRAME NAME="M_RFrame" SRC="M_RFrm.asp" MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="auto" FRAMEBORDER="yes">
</FRAMESET>
```

Both forms with the M_LFrm.asp and the M_RFrm.asp have asp logic calling the Database for information.  Prior to calling the DB I would like to have a CSRF token check but am unsure how to pass a token into these forms as they are through Frames which are Gets and visible.  Is there a way to call these forms with a POST?

Thank you.

Comment: you could create a session value before displaying forms then pick up that session value in the asp logic

Comment: @Dee: That isn't a comment its the answer so post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In classic asp using a POST instead of a GET is a matter of changing your form from method="get" to method="post".

The ASP code that *handles* the form data will have a "request.querystring()" or "request()" instruction for fetching the form data.

- request.querystring("[formfield
  name]") can access GET data
- request.form("[formfield name]") can
  access POST data
- request("[formfield name]") can
  access both POST and GET data

So to change the code from using GET to POST, in the ASP code you will need to change any request.querystring() instructions to request.form() or simply request()

hope this helps,